# What is the difference between Breit-Wigner mass and pole mass in PDG?

Tags: particle-physics, mass-energy

In Review of Particle Physics 2014, page 81, in the baryon summary table, there are usually noticeable differences between Re(pole position) and Breit-Wigner mass, for example, for $N(1440)$, $M_{BW}=1430\pm10$ MeV, while Re(pole position)=1365$\pm$15 MeV. Does this result from different parameterizations to the experimental curves?